# Rshiny table row data wrap

Tags: r

In Rshiny i want to wrap the data in the table.How can i do that below is the code

```
    fluidRow(
        column(4,
               tableOutput('table')
        )

tags$style(HTML('#table{word-wrap: break-word;}')),
```

But it is not reflecting.I am newbie to UI